# ObservableCollection didn't update

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I have a problem with my ObservableCollection and i don't know how do it.
I have connection with my SQl base (use EF).

```
 public class ProductModel 

{
    private static List<ProductDbObject> ProductDbObjects { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ProductDbObject> OProductDbObjects { get; set; }

    public ProductModel()
    {
        CollectionChanged();

    }
    public void CollectionChanged()
    {
        ProductDbObjects = new List<ProductDbObject>();
        ProductDbObjects = Services.productService.GetAll();
        OProductDbObjects = new ObservableCollection<ProductDbObject>(ProductDbObjects);
    }
}
```

}

I Get all items from base and save it in list and list in ObservableCollection.

```
<Window x:Class="NoweChili.View.AdminView.EditProductView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NoweChili.View.AdminView"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Edycja Produktów" Height="600" Width="800">

<Grid Margin="20" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name ="ProductListListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding OProductDbObjects}" ></ListView>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="ProductEditButton" Click="ProductEditButton_OnClick" Content="Edytuj"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="ProductDeleteButton" Click="ProductDeleteButton_OnClick" Content="Usuń" Grid.Row="2"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="ProductBackButton"  Content="Cofnij" Grid.Row="4"></Button>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Item show right, but when i delete one of them, the observableCollection didn't update and item still be on list.

```
 private void ProductDeleteButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       ProductDbObject productToDelete = new ProductDbObject();
        productToDelete = (ProductDbObject) ProductListListView.SelectedItem;
        if (productToDelete == null)
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Proszę zaznaczyć obiekt na liście");
        }

        else
        {
            Services.productService.DeleteEntity(productToDelete);
            Services.productService.SaveChange();            
        }
```

Can u help me ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that although you have used the service to delete the product, that doesn't remove the product from your ObservableCollection - you would need to call Remove(productToDelete)

Comment: U have right :)

 productModel.OProductDbObjects.Remove(productToDelete); solve this problem :) Thanks